# Question regarding Cauchy Integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I have a question regarding Cauchy Integral formula,
I was given an assignment questions, and my professor uploaded a solution and i do not understand how he reached to an answer with his method. Can anyone provide me with a clearer method? [Part 2][image]

[image: Solution]

Comment: I'm confused as to where you're stuck, the stuff you showed looks like he just used the literal statement of the residue theorem. Where precisely are you confused? Do you understand the theorem itself?

Comment: Yeah, I just don't understand how he's going from 2nd step to directly to  the answer, so yeah I'm confused with the theorem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**:

The solutions to $z^{10}+2=0$ are found as

$$z^{10}=-2\implies z^{10}=2e^{i(2n+1)\pi}\implies z=2^{1/10}e^{i(2n+1)\pi/10}\implies |z|=2^{1/10}<2$$

Thus, all roots of $z^{10}+2=0$ lie within the region $|z|<2$.  Therefore, the poles of $\frac{z^{10}}{(z-1/2)(z^{10}+2)}$ are at $z=1/2$ and $z=2^{1/10}e^{\pm i(2n+1)\pi/10}$ for $n=0,1,2,3,4$.